# is this the right way to call socket Send/Receive

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, winsock, blocking

My discussion is based on connected TCP, blocking sockets, synchronization.

Firstly about `Receive()`, MSDN says:

> If no data is available for reading, the `Receive()` method will block until data is available.If you are using a connection-oriented Socket, the `Receive()` method will read as much data as is available up to the size of the buffer.

The emphasis on blocking made me misunderstand this passage. Later I did experiments and reached the following conclusions: If I want to accept 10 bytes, but only 6 bytes are readable in the socket cache, calling `Receive()` once does not block until 10 bytes are readable. Only to return, but as much as possible to read the now readable byte, that is, 6 bytes will be returned, so the actual number of bytes read is represented by the return value of `Receive()`. So I think I should call `recvToCnt()` instead of `Receive()` if I want to exactly receive the specified number of bytes.

```
private int recvToCnt(Socket socket, byte[] buf, int beginIndex, int cnt)
{
   if (buf.Length < beginIndex + cnt)
      return 0;

   int realCnt = 0;
   while (realCnt < cnt)
   {
      realCnt += socket.Receive(buf, beginIndex + realCnt, cnt - realCnt, SocketFlags.None);
   }
   return realCnt;
}
```

Then, let's see `Send()`. MSDN says:

> If you are using a connection-oriented protocol, `Send()` will block until all of the bytes in the buffer are sent, unless a time-out was set by using `Socket.SendTimeout()`.

I doubt the accuracy of this description, because `Send()` also has a return value, I guess it should have a similar blocking concept to `Receive()`. So I guess I should use `sendToCnt()` instead of sending if I want to make sure that the specified number of bytes is sent into the socket cache:

```
private int sendToCnt(Socket socket, byte[] buf, int beginIndex, int cnt)
{
   if (buf.Length < beginIndex + cnt)
      return 0;

   int realCnt = 0;
   while (realCnt < cnt)
   {
      realCnt += socket.Send(buf, beginIndex + realCnt, cnt - realCnt, SocketFlags.None);
   }
   return realCnt;
}
```

Is my idea correct? Any other idea?

Comment: Your `recvToCnt` code will spin in an endless loop if the other side closes the connection or there's an error.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if an error occurs, an exception is thrown. But you are correct about the other side closing the connection. The code needs to handle the case where `Receive()` returns 0 to indicate the connection has been closed gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I want to accept 10 bytes, but only 6 bytes are readable in the socket cache,

The socket receive buffer.

> ... calling `Receive()` once does not block until 10 bytes are readable. Only to return, but as much as possible to read the now readable byte, that is, 6 bytes will be returned, so the actual number of bytes read is represented by the return value of `Receive()`.

Correct.

> So I think I should call `recvToCnt()` instead of `Receive()` if I want exactly receive specify bytes.

You should certainly call `Receive()` in a loop until you have all the data you are expecting, or an error or end of stream occurs, but the code you posted ignores errors and end of stream completely, which is not acceptable. You need to fix that.

> Then, let's see `Send()`. ... I doubt the accuracy of this description,

Don't. It is correct, in blocking mode.

> because `Send()` also has a return value, I guess it should have similar blocking concept with `Receive()`.

No. The return value becomes significant in non-blocking mode. In blocking mode it behaves as described.

> So I guess I should use `sendToCnt()` instead of sending if I want to make sure that the specified number of bytes is sent into the socket cache

The socket send buffer, and no, and again the code you posted ignores errors, which once again is unacceptable.

Comment: "*the [recvToCnt()] code you posted ignores errors and end of stream completely*" - socket errors throw exceptions. `recvToCnt()` doesn't need to handle exceptions directly, let the caller decide how to handle them. But you are correct that it does need to handle end-of-stream, at least. `Receive()` returns 0 when the socket has been closed gracefully. "*the [sendToCnt()] code you posted ignores errors*" - `Send()` doesn't return a value on error, it throws an exception, including on socket closure. So `sendToCnt()` doesn't need to handle errors, let the caller handle that.

Comment: "*The return value [of Send()] becomes significant in non-blocking mode. In blocking mode it behaves as described*" - no, even in blocking mode, it *can* return fewer bytes than requested (though may times it *won't* need to).  So you have to call `Send()` in a loop, too.

Comment: @Remy: Important to note that the question is about an unspecified object-oriented wrapper around the socket API, not about Winsock functions.  (It is mistagged somewhat).  It's possible that the wrapper behaves a bit differently than the underlying socket APIs.

Comment: @BenVoigt the wrapper in question is .NET's `Socket` class (the quotes are from MSDN's `Socket` documentation). What I said applies to that class. I checked its source code, it does not loop internally to ensure all requested bytes are read/sent before exiting, so you have to loop in your own code, just like we using Winsock functions directly

Comment: @RemyLebeau `Receive()` does indeed return zero at end of stream, and the OP is ignoring it, so his code will loop forever. Re `Send()`, you're arguing with MSDN here, not with me. Posix also says it must be so for the BSD Sockets API and the Posix `write()` method, in blocking mode, unless an interrupt occurs, whose semantics I have never been able to figure out in 27 years. That's a lot of primary sources to be arguing with.

Comment: @BenVoigt Provided `Send(a,b,c,d)` essentially calls `send(a,b,c,d)`, it can't possibly have different (i.e. shorter) semantics.

Comment: @EJP: I suppose you mean that `a.Send(b, c, d)` calls `send(a.Handle, b, c, d)`... but even in that case, the semantics can be different, between wrappers can (and do) mess with socket options.  For example, if that .NET (have we proven the wrapper OP is using is .NET?) Socket object was gotten from a `TcpClient` instance's `Client` property (which is annoyingly named, the same class is used when accepting a server-side connected socket from a listening socket), it's almost certain to have socket options set on it beyond those OP explicitly called a `setsockopt`-equivalent for.

Answer (score 1):

> If I want to accept 10 bytes, but only 6 bytes are readable in the socket cache, calling `Receive()` once does not block until 10 bytes are readable. Only to return, but as much as possible to read the now readable byte, that is, 6 bytes will be returned, so the actual number of bytes read is represented by the return value of `Receive()`.

Yes.

> So I think I should call `recvToCnt()` instead of `Receive()` if I want to exactly receive the specified number of bytes.

Yes.

> I doubt the accuracy of this description, because `Send()` also has a return value, I guess it should have a similar blocking concept to `Receive()`.

Yes.  It *can* return fewer bytes than requested, if the socket's kernel buffer has enough space for *at least* 1 byte but does not have enough space for *all* of the bytes you are sending.

> So I guess I should use `sendToCnt()` instead of sending if I want to make sure that the specified number of bytes is sent into the socket cache:

Yes.